# SQL Server : dynamic concat not working with case in order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, dynamic-sql

I have a issue where concat isn't concatenating rows into a single string.

Here is the row data

- <B>Case1 Number</B>: 123<BR/>
- <B>Contact Email</B>: dfFff<BR/>
- <B>Contact Phone Number</B>: <BR/>
- <B>Reason for Escalation</B>: fddf<BR/>
- <B>Contact Preference</B>: Email<BR/>

This is the query that works

```
declare @body nvarchar(MAX),
@details  nvarchar(MAX)

set @details = ''

select @details = @details + '&lt;B&gt;' + f.name + '&lt;/B&gt;: ' + COALESCE( s.select_value, d.field_data) + CHAR(13)+'&lt;BR/&gt;'
from primaryTable d
inner join fields f on f.field_id = d.field_id
left outer join select_fields s on s.field_id = d.field_id 
                                and s.select_text = d.field_data
where data_id = 123
order by f.sort_id
```

This query doesn't work

```
declare @body nvarchar(MAX),
@details  nvarchar(MAX)

set @details = ''

select @details = @details + '&lt;B&gt;' + f.name + '&lt;/B&gt;: ' + COALESCE( s.select_value, d.field_data) + CHAR(13)+'&lt;BR/&gt;'
from primaryTable d
inner join fields f on f.field_id = d.field_id
left outer join select_fields s on s.field_id = d.field_id 
                                and s.select_text = d.field_data
where data_id = 123
order by
        case 
            when f.parent_id = 0 
               then f.sort_id
               else (select  fs.sort_id + 1
                     from fields fs
                     where fs.field_id = f.parent_id) 
        end, 
        case 
           when f.sort_id = 0 then 1 
        end desc,  
        f.sort_id
```

The above query only returns

```
&lt;B&gt;Contact Phone Number&lt;/B&gt;: 
&lt;BR/&gt;
```

I am using SQL Server 2012

As per request here are the table DDL

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[primaryTable ](
    [na_fields_data_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [data_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [field_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [field_data] [varchar](max) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__na_survey__field__1332DBDC]  DEFAULT (NULL),
 CONSTRAINT [PK__na_surve__5E098220114A936A] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [na_fields_data_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO



 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[select_fields](
    [field_select_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [field_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [select_text] [varchar](255) NULL DEFAULT (NULL),
    [select_value] [varchar](255) NULL DEFAULT (NULL),
    [sort_id] [int] NULL DEFAULT (NULL),
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [field_select_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[fields ](
    [field_select_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [field_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [select_text] [varchar](255) NULL DEFAULT (NULL),
    [select_value] [varchar](255) NULL DEFAULT (NULL),
    [sort_id] [int] NULL DEFAULT (NULL),
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [field_select_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: What I don't understand why it concats xml entities like `&lt;` instead of the actual characters like `<`. And the only difference between those queries is the ORDER BY? that shouldn't influence how many tags are added to the variable... Odd.

Comment: Btw, I would use CONCAT instead of `+` to concatinate the strings. Because `+` returns NULL if a NULL is added, while CONCAT doesn't.

Comment: The behavior of aggregate string concatenation (i.e. `@details = @details +`) in SQL Server is undefined. You might or might not get the expected results depending on the query plan. Use `STRING_AGG` in SQL 2017 and later (including Azure SQL Database) and `FOR XML PATH` in older versions. Add `CREATE TABLE` DDL to your question if you need an example.

Comment: @LukStorms the reason i have xml entities is because this data first gets inserted into a SQL table and then the data is then used to be injected into mongoDB and emails.

also can you provide me a example of using concat with the above query? i couldn't get it to work

Comment: @DanGuzman i can not use SQL 2017, we are limited to 2012 and an example would really be help here for the above query

Comment: @TheConfusedCoder  simplified example : `declare @details nvarchar(max); 
select @details = concat(@details+CHAR(13),'<b>',f.name,'</b>') from (values ('col1'),('col2'),('col3')) as f(name);
select @details;`

Comment: @TheConfusedCoder, add CREATE TABLE DDL to your question if you need an example. INSERT statements will facilitate a tested solution.

Comment: @DanGuzman sorry but i am not able to understand what do you mean by " add CREATE TABLE DDL" to your question ? should i edit my question and add the line "Create table DDL" somewhere in there?

Comment: @TheConfusedCoder, DDL (data definition language) statements are CREATE TABLE statements. These scripts can be generated from SSMS Object Explorer by right-clicking on the table and selecting Script Table As-->Create to,,,

Comment: @DanGuzman Thank you, as per your request i added the DDL's for the tables used in the query

Comment: @LukStorms i tried this statement "select details = CONCAT(@details + '&lt;B&gt;' + f.name + '&lt;/B&gt;: ' , COALESCE( s.select_value, d.field_data) + CHAR(13)+'&lt;BR/&gt;')" and it did not work

Comment: Your statement is missing the `@` after `select`. And still has many `+` that could be `,`

Comment: @TheConfusedCoder, I get error "Invalid column name 'name'." when I run this query with your table. Please post the correct query and add `INSERT` statements that produce the row data in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late response, i got completely caught up with other stuff.

So the way i solved was this by taking the dynamic sql output and dumping it into a temp table and then using the temp table to contact the final output.

Example:

```
select '&lt;B&gt;' + f.name + '&lt;/B&gt;: ' + COALESCE( s.select_value, d.field_data) + CHAR(13)+'&lt;BR/&gt;' 'SELECTVALUE'
into #TempDump 
from primaryTable d
inner join fields f on f.field_id = d.field_id
left outer join select_fields s on s.field_id = d.field_id 
                                and s.select_text = d.field_data
where data_id = 123
order by
        case 
            when f.parent_id = 0 
               then f.sort_id
               else (select  fs.sort_id + 1
                     from fields fs
                     where fs.field_id = f.parent_id) 
        end, 
        case 
           when f.sort_id = 0 then 1 
        end desc,  
        f.sort_id

SELECT @details = @details + x.SELECTVALUE FROM #TempDump x
```